# Best way to call a jQuery function from keyup on multiple fields?

Tags: jquery, function

I have a function which I want to call any time a user hits a key in any one of several fields.

I can achieve this by:

```
$("#a").keyup(function(){
    myfunction();
}); 
$("#b").keyup(function(){
    myfunction();
});
$("#c").keyup(function(){
    myfunction();  
});
$("#d").keyup(function(){
    myfunction();
});
```

but is there something like

```
$("#a","#b","#c","#d").keyup(function(){
    myfunction();
});
```

That would be more elegant?

(Incidentally I tried the above and it did not work)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xoyrx4dv/2/)

EDIT: I accepted David Escudero's answer below, as it answers the question I asked. However Erik Philips points out that it would be better to give all relevant fields a class and then call the event on keyup of that class. Which I can see is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a mistake on your fiddle, you didn't put `function` on it.

`myfunction(){` to `function myfunction(){`

Then, you are putting double quotes on each selector.
`$("#a","#b","#c","#d").keyup(function(){`

Change that to

`$("#a,#b,#c,#d").keyup(function(){`

**Putting together:**

```js
function myfunction(){
   $("#result").append('<p>It worked!</p><br/>');
}

$("#a,#b,#c,#d").keyup(function(){
 myfunction();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="a" />
<input type="number" id="b" />
<input type="number" id="c" />
<input type="number" id="d" />

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Ah, great  - thanks for catching both the lack of function (that was just a silly mistake transferring it to jsfiddle) but also the quote strucutre. 

I'll mark yours as the right answer as it has the most detail, though you have a typo under "Change that to" where you didn't remove the quotes. (I can tell what you mean from the example though). Fix that and I'll accept the answer when the time runs down - thanks!

Comment: you can also use input selector if it's for any fields in the page  `$(":input")`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a fan of any of these solutions (including your examples).  They are all tightly coupled and reduce re-usability.  Take a quick read of [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](http://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).

I would highly recommend:

```
$(".js-myfunction").on('keyup', function(){
  myfunction();
});


<input type="text" value="Gideon" class="js-myfunction" />
```

Create a class you want to apply to all elements. This way instead of changing your Javascript everytime you need to add or remove an element, you change your html elements.  Anyone reading your HTML knows what elements will execute your method (automatically).  And your Javascript is not tightly coupled to HTML elements.

Comment: I can see these are wise words, and I will bear them in mind when I carry on learning javascript. But for now writing a class for this is outside my ability/time.

Comment: I've given an example of the class (it took all of 5 seconds) and the javascript I wrote already works for it...

Comment: Oh ... a class! Sorry I had my PHP head on, and was thinking of "class" as something more complex. Ok I completely understand, yes I can see this is better. Ok - well thank you, I will implement this. But I will accept another answer as it technically the answer to what I asked, in case anyone needs it for a more valid reason than my case. I will however edit the question to highlight your comments (Is that reasonable SO ettiquette?)

Comment: The accepted answer is the one that helped *you* to most.  Each person can vote on what they feel is the most appropriate answer(s).  No need to mention my answer, if people are interested they should just read all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Just treat your jQuery selection like a CSS selector:

```
$("#a, #b, #c, #d").keyup(function(){
    myfunction();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#a, #b, #c, #d').keyup(myfunction);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xoyrx4dv/1/